# Finding an isomorphism between $(U\otimes V)^{\mathsf T}$ and $B(U \times V,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: metric-spaces, graph-isomorphism

> Prove the isomorphism between $(U\otimes V)^{\mathsf T}$ and $B(U \times V,\mathbb{R})$, where $B$ is the collection of all bi-linear mappings. In order to do so, give a natural isomorphism between the two spaces.

My problem is that I can't really picture the two spaces. Thus, I also find it really hard to see how I could transform the one space into the other. Could anyone please help me out? It would be highly appreciated, I don't have a clue where to start.

Any help on finding isomorphisms in general would also be very welcome.

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful. If you need to format more advanced things, there are many excellent references on LaTeX on the internet, including StackExchange's own [TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Thanks, Ill definately look into that later. However, could you please try to help me out with this question?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Do you maybe have a clue on how I could do this question? Do you know how I can find isomorphisms such as these in general?

Comment: What does $\mathsf{T}$ mean? What's your definition of the tensor product?

Comment: T is the transpose. I dont know what definition is used to be honest. I am not very familiar to the concept of a tensor yet unfortunately. @ChrisEagle

Comment: @user48288: So you have no idea what a tensor product is, but you're trying to prove things about it. Can't you see that this is a fruitless endeavour? You'd better find out your definition before doing anything else.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I do know what a tensor product is, though I am not yet very familiar with its properties and how to do proofs with it. And I thought you were referring to a certain ambuigity that might exist in the defintion of the tensor product, so therefore I said that I dont know which definition is used.

Answer (score 3):

It is quite hopeless to answer such a question if we do not know what is meant by the "transpose". I guess it might mean the dual vector space i.e. that you are supposed to show that

$(U\otimes{V})^{*}=Hom(U\otimes{V},\mathbb{R})\cong{B(U\times{V},\mathbb{R}})$

This is true almost by the definition of the tensor product, more specifically by its universal property. Are you familiar with that?

This universal property is as follows: for every bilinear map $\phi:U\times{V}\rightarrow{W}$ there exists a unique linear map $\psi:U\otimes{V}\rightarrow{W}$ such that $\psi\circ{f}=\phi$, where $f:U\times{V}\rightarrow{U\otimes{V}}$ is the map $(x,y)\mapsto{x\otimes{y}}$ i.e. such that $\psi(u\otimes{v})=\phi(u,v)$. That is, bilinear maps from $U\times{V}$ correspond to
linear maps from $U\otimes{V}$

However, once you know this there isn't really much to prove.. Is this an exercise found in a book?

Answer (score 0):

For example, see lectures on Algebra II:

http://www.math.toronto.edu/jkamnitz/courses/mat247/